# What customization or init files are there in Beaker Notebook?

Tags: beaker-notebook

I'd like to modify the UI in Beaker Notebook.  What customization or init files are available for this?

Answer (score 1):

**~/.beaker/v1/config/beaker.pref.json** is read at startup and can modify the UI in many ways. See its [documentation](https://github.com/twosigma/beaker-notebook/wiki/Language-Preferences), including how to [manipulate the menus](https://github.com/twosigma/beaker-notebook/wiki/Configuration-and-Preference).